# How to pass unsigned bytes to SecretKeySpec()?

Tags: java, byte, unsigned

I need to use Java's `SecretKeySpec()` with an array of numbers greater than 127.

If I do the following:

```
new byte[] { (byte)0xD9, (byte)0xDF, (byte)0x85 }
```

the numbers get converted to bytes and they'll be negative.

Of course I can `&` them with `0xFF` and save them in a `short` array and save their value, but then I won't be able to pass this array to `SecretKeySpec()`, because it receives only a `bytes[]` array.

Any ideas?

Comment: If SecretKeySpec takes a byte[] than you must assume it handles the values > 127 correctly. What is your actual problem?

Comment: Writing this: `new byte[] { 0xD9, 0xDF, 0x85 }` generates an error. It needs to be like this: `new byte[] { (byte)0xD9, (byte)0xDF, (byte)0x85 }`. And if it's like this, then the numbers are converted to signed numbers. So I'm already passing a wrong array...

Comment: You cannot have a byte that equals  128, because there isn't an unsigned byte. So the SecretKeySpec must handle it accordingly. Why do you say it is the wrong array?

Comment: `{ 0xD9, 0xDF, 0x85 } =  {217, 223, 133}`, but `{ (byte)0xD9, (byte)0xDF, (byte)0x85 } = {-39, -33, -123}`

Comment: That is the way it should be. What error is that causing. If you just want to display the unsigned version you can use Byte.toUnsignedInt.

Comment: I don't "just want to display the unsigned version". I need `SecretKeySpec()` to work on these exact numbers: `{217, 223, 133}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there's no need to do that.
I do write signed values to `byte[]` array in Java, and do read them as unsigned in C# (e.g Java's `-16` reads `240` in C#). But the decryption still works. Seems like this is taken care of in the Rijndael algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This is really just a rendering issue.  `SecretKeySpec` works with a byte array, and you have no problem constructing a byte array.  The only question is how to represent large (>127) integers as java bytes, or equivalently, what you mean by '217' as a byte.

You could use whatever mapping you want, but Java has a pretty natural choice - to convert an integer to a byte, use a cast, `(byte)i`, and to convert back, use `Byte.toUnsignedInt(b)`.  As you can see, this recovers the original values:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    for (int count = 0; count<256; count++){
        System.out.println(count+" : "+(byte)count+" => "+Byte.toUnsignedInt((byte)count));
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is what do I pass to `SecretKeySpec()`? From the documentations: *Creates a new SecretKeySpec for the specified key data and algorithm name.* So it would work differently on the number 217 and -39. And I need it to work on 217

Comment: I see that *"This class is only useful for raw secret keys that can be represented as a byte array..."*. And the numbers in my example cannot be represented as a byte array so I guess it's just not possible

Comment: You *can* represent 217 as a byte, the only question is which byte, and there's a natural canonical way to do this.  Also, the mapping only matters if you're trying to reproduce a `SecretKeySpec` created from another source - is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Some hard-coded key is used for encryption in **C#**, and I need to use the same hard-coded key in **Java**, for the **C#**'s decryption algorithm (i can't change this) to work on the generated **Java** encrypted data. And `bytes` in **C#** are unsigned...

Comment: I'd say it's pretty likely that this is the mapping which would be used there.  Not 100%, but to be sure you'd have to dig through the C# documentation and see how its binary representation of integers corresponds to Java.  (Or just try it and see)

Comment: Also, I hope that key isn't the one you've posted here?  (Can never be too careful!)

Comment: Haha it's not. This is just an example. And OK I'll look into it, thanks.